# Transferring large amounts of data in web editor

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a web editor for fun and I was told that the way I was doing it (using PHP) would be a bad way. I also thought about it while I was making it, and in massive sums of data transfer it would be a bad idea to do it this way. I can't think of another way to do it and was looking for someone to help me improve it, by that I mean my save method I am using.

**Editor:**

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Web Editor</title>
    <link href="controller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/editor.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="platform">
      <div class="head">
        <div class="file">
          <p>File:
            <div id="file">C:\hello.html</div>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hotbar">
        <img src="images/save.png" class="hotbarImage" onClick="save()" />
      </div>
      <div class="editor">
        <div contenteditable="true" style="height:100%; overflow:scroll;" id="editPad"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```js
function save() {
  var dir = document.getElementById("file").innerHTML;
  var data = document.getElementById("editPad").innerHTML;
  window.location = "save.php?dir=" + encodeURIComponent(dir) + "&data=" + encodeURIComponent(data);
}
```

**PHP:**

```php
<?php
    $dir = $_GET['dir'];
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    $lookFor = array("&lt;", "&gt;","<br>","<%2Fdiv>","<div>","</div>");
    $replaceWith = array("<", ">", "", "", "","");
    $newData = str_replace($lookFor,$replaceWith,$data);

    $f = fopen(urldecode($dir),"w");
    fwrite($f,urldecode($newData));
    fclose($f);
?>
```

All of it is just a work in progress and I need more done. But for right now, is there a better way for me to save the file with massive sums of data being transferred?

Comment: How much data do you expect per transfer?

Comment: Up to a MB. That should probably be the largest amount.

Answer (score 2):

- I'd prefer a form with a textarea rather than a contenteditable element. Forms and text areas were built for that purpose.
- As for your save code, `GET` requests should not do anything on the server. It should only do what it was called to do, and that is to *get data*. I suggest you do a `POST` or `PUT` instead by using a form, or via AJAX.
- An advantage of AJAX compared to forms is that you won't leave your page. Similar to how you did it, you grab the data and send it to the server.
- Your editor is risky since it can write to an arbitrary file on the server (or worse, on the system). With this code, I can modify this PHP file itself and make it do all kinds of stuff. I suggest you do some research on how you can restrict where and what you can modify.
- You need a more robust approach in stripping HTML from the data than doing it manually. PHP has some built-in functions to do that for you, like `strip_tags`. There could be better solutions that I'm not aware of as well.
- Massive data? How much data do you expect you put in anyway? I suggest *polishing the implementation first* before optimizing for other stuff, like data size and so on.